# Complexity class NP and MA

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Is there any example of any natural problem which is known to be in MA, but not yet to known to be in NP?

I am aware that Graph Nonisomorphism (GNI) is known to be in AM which is considered a superset of MA. Can we construct a language (which may be non-natural) which is in MA, but not in NP?

Comment: Since MA is in the polynomial hierarchy, there is no such unconditional result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same hardness assumption that implies P=BPP also implies NP=MA (at least according to the [complexity zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#ma)).

Even if the hardness assumption is wrong, separating NP from MA would be a huge achievement, since it would imply that P is different from NP (as MA is in the polynomial hierarchy).

Comment: Yes. separating NP from MA unconditionally would be very hard. (even showing their equality will lead to NEXP $\not\subset$ P/poly, which seems very hard to prove). But my question is a little different: Is something known to be in MA, but not (known) to be in NP (or at least we are unable to prove it is in NP yet)? For example: We can prove GNI is in AM, but it is not known to be in MA (or NP) yet. (Still they are not ruled out).

Comment: For example: A lot of problems are known to be in BPP, but not in P (Polynomial Identity Testing being one example). Similarly, Does the same thing happen in their non-deterministic counterpart as well?